# Exclude resources from android:generate-sources

Tags: android, build, resources, maven-2

Could someone give me an idea about how to exclude using Maven, some resources? I have a lot of languages in my project and I want to make build only for 3 languages for example. I have create the pom file and when I make the apk, all resources are copy by default (resources:resources,"Copying 122 resources"). Can I make in any way to create the apk only with the language resources that I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the additional languages into a separate maven project and use the maven android plugin apksources dependency way to pull them in. If you do that in separate projects you could do all you development e.g. without all the internationalized files and then e.g. only in the release build use the apksources dependency to pull the internationalization in.

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkSourcesDependency

Answer (score 0):

I would create various profiles for the various languages and use specific [resources inclusion/exclusion rules](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) per profile.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial page for using library resources - it may help you acheive a shared resources model. Note that android SDK 2.0 and pre-1.5 are not capable of creating libraries for some reason. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject